# In Google Sheets, I want a sheet's name to be updated based value of a cell (which changes regularly based on a formula)

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet, I want the name of the sheet to be updated and be whatever the value is in a cell. The value of the cell changes based off a formula. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible to change automatically with onEdt(e), however we need to know the arguments of the formula. Can you share this formula?

Comment: The formula in D4 is "=average (C7+C14) " --  p.s. c7 & c14 are based on another formula.

Comment: It's important to know the deeper origin of the data, because onEdit will only trigger on manual editing. So can you give the origin of the calculation of C7 and C14 and so on? However, I will prepare an answer.

Comment: It could be easier to answer if you can give an example in a simplified spreadsheet which shows where are the manually modified cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (cel.getA1Notation()=='X1' || cel.getA1Notation()=='Y1'){
    sh.setName(sh.getRange('Z1').getValue())
  }
}
```

where

- X1, Y1 ... are the deeper origin of the data, manually updated
- Z1 the cell that contains the expected name of the sheet

If the sheet you want to rename is not the active one, you have to identify it by it's ID, you have first to test `event.source.getActiveSheet()` and then determine the sheet to be renamed, for instance:

```
  var shId = 1353792204
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets().filter(function(s) {return s.getSheetId() === shId;})[0];
```

Comment: I don't have domain knowledge here so I'm asking out of curiosity: Does this use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)? If so, you might want to indicate that in your answer. The asker didn't use the [tag:google-apps-script] tag so maybe they don't know what it is.